# Caffe: Understanding expected lmdb datastructure for blobs

Tags: caffe, lmdb

I'm trying to understand how data is interpreted in Caffe.
For that I've taken a look at the [Minst Tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/mnist.html)
Looking at the input data definition:

```
layers {
  name: "mnist"
  type: DATA
  data_param {
    source: "mnist_train_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 64
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
}
```

I've now looked at the mnist_train_lmdb and taken one of the entries (shown in hex):

```
0801101C181C229006
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000054B99F973C2400000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000DEFEFEFEFEF1C6C6C6C6C6C6C6C6AA34000000000000
00000000000043724872A3E3FEE1FEFEFEFAE5FEFE8C000000000000
000000000000000000000011420E4343433B15ECFE6A000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000053FDD112000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000016E9FF5300000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000081FEEE2C00000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000003BF9FE3E0000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000085FEBB050000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000009CDF83A000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000007EFEB600000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000004BFBF03900000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000013DDFEA60000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000003CBFEDB230000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000026FEFE4D000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001FE0FE7301000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000085FEFE3400000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000003DF2FEFE3400000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000079FEFEDB2800000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000079FECF120000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2807
```

(I've added the line breaks here to be able to see the '7' digit.)

Now my question is, **where this format is described?** Or put differently where is defined that the first 36 bytes are some sort of header and the last 8 bytes have some label correspondence?

**How would I go about constructing my own data?**
Neither [Blob Tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) nor [Layers Definition](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html) give much away about required formats. *My intention is not to use image data, but time series*

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I realized that protocol buffers must come into play here. So I tried to deserialize it against some of the types defined in [caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto).

**Datum** seems to be the perfect fit:

```
{Caffe.Datum}
    Channels: 1
    Data: {byte[784]}
    Encoded: false
    FloatData: Count = 0
    Height: 28
    Label: 7
    Width: 28
```

So the answer is simply: **It's a serialized representation of a 'Datum' typed instance as defined per [caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto)**

*Btw. since english is not my native language I had to first realize that "Datum" is a singular form of "data"*

When it comes to using your own data, it's structured as follows:

> The conventional blob dimensions for data are number N x channel
>   K x height H x width W. Blob memory is row-major in layout so the last
>   / rightmost dimension changes fastest. For example, the value at index
>   (n, k, h, w) is physically located at index ((n * K + k) * H + h) * W
>   + w.

See [Blobs, Layers, and Nets: anatomy of a Caffe model](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) for reference

Comment: "Datum" = an individual piece of data - like a case

Comment: Did you manage to create a LMDB file in a C++ program? Not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: I was using C# not C++, but yes after understanding the above it was pretty easy to connect it to LMDB

Answer (score 2):

I can try to answer your second question. Since Caffe only takes data in a bunch of selected formats like lmdb, hdf5 etc., it is best to convert (or generate - in case of synthetic data) your data to these formats. Following links can help you in this. If you have trouble with `import hdf5`in Python, then you may refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30769048/error-in-creating-lmdb-database-file-in-python-for-caffe?answertab=votes#tab-top) page.

[Creating an LMDB file in Python](http://deepdish.io/2015/04/28/creating-lmdb-in-python/)

[Writing an HDF5 file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466971/fastest-way-to-write-hdf5-file-with-python)

[HDF5 more examples](http://download.nexusformat.org/sphinx/examples/h5py/index.html)